# On the construction of a Brownian motion from a Gaussian process

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability, brownian-motion, girsanov, vasicek

Let $X$ a Gaussian process defined by 
$$
X_t=\int_{0}^{t}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma}\left(r_s-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)-\rho\sigma_P(s,T)\right)\mathrm{d}s+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2(t)+\rho Z_1(t);\;\;t\in[0,T]
$$
Where $\sigma>0$, $T>0$, $\rho\in]-1,+1[$, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ two independent Brownian motion defined on the same probability space, $\sigma_P(s,T)$ a deterministic function and $r_t$ a process whose dynamics are described by the Vasicek model.

My problem is to define a new probability measure under which the process $X$ is a Brownian motion. The theorem Girsanov allows this construction when the Novikov condition is checked, namely:
$$
E\left(\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{T}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma}\left(r_s-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)-\rho\sigma_P(s,T)\right)^2\mathrm{d}s)  \right)\right)<\infty
$$
I would like your opinion on this issue, thank you in advance.

Comment: do you want to know how to apply Girsanov ? or you are not sure if Novikov condition is verified ?

Comment: Yes, my problem is to check the condition of Novikov. thank you.